# Save as PDF using the Firefox mxt08-real/Export-Web-to-PDF extension

Tags: macos, firefox, pdf, firefox-extensions, finder

- MacOS Ventura 13.6.3
- Firefox 123 and 124b (developper edition)

I am testing the [mxt08-real/Export-Web-to-PDF](https://github.com/mxt08-real/Export-Web-to-PDF) Firefox extension, which allows to add an icon to trigger the "Save as PDF" popup.

[image]

It works, but there is a problem: even if the format is correctly set to "PDF" in the save popup window.

[image]

The default proposed file name (which is generated from the title attribute of the webpage I guess), doesn't have the ".pdf" extension.
Therefore, when the file is saved, it is considered as an unknown type, by macOS:

[image]

So, is there a way to force the ".pdf" extension? Is it a bug in the extension? If yes, how can it be fixed?